# No or very poor cell signal in areas I know have good signal

Tags: connection-issues, motorola

My phone worked fine till about the middle of yesterday. I live out in the country but usually I see 3 to 4 bars sitting at my desk in the basement. But now even if I walk up to the top of the hill (200 ft) on the property, from which I can see 3 cell towers, the signal comes and goes. For about 30 seconds there is full strength and then nothing, and I mean absolute zero signal, for a minute or 2. I had this problem last year as the phone was in warranty I just got a replacement. I figured the antenna wasn't connected correctly and it came loose. But to suddenly get this bad again, and I am sure I haven't dropped or jarred phone, I have to think something else is screwed up.

This morning I figure since I hadn't done any updates in a while I should do them. I used my WiFi connection to update and it worked for a couple minutes after I did the update, then the signal was gone again. This makes me think some setting is messed up but where and how to fix it is my problem.

As I drive around I get signal, but noticeably I have to be closer to a tower to get signal and then it gives me 4 to 5 bars otherwise nothing.

I have checked the "Mobile Network" settings; "Roaming" is on, "Preferred Network Type" is set to "Global", and "Enhanced 4G LTE Mode" is on. I have tried changing them all but no difference.

If it is relevant my phone is Motorola Moto E6

This is such an odd problem I am not even sure where to start digging for answers